# How do I catch Flutter Google sign-in PlatformException?

Tags: ios, dart, google-signin, flutter

Following the brilliant [Firebase Flutter](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) tutorial, I'm trying to incorporate Google sign-in into my app.

The flow: If not logged in, user will always arrive at login page (via checks at the `MaterialApp`'s `onGenerateRoute`), user then presses the Login button and redirected to the Google sign-in flow. However, should the user cancel the flow midway, I'd like to return to the login page, forcing her to press the button again.

I fail to catch the PlatformException for some reason (you can see it in the debugger, and the app hanging in the simulator):
[image: the exception in the debugger, the app hangs in the simulator]

The code I'm using:

```
  Future<bool> logIn() async {
    print('Login::logIn()');
    bool loggedIn = await logInSilently();
    print('Login::logIn() - silent login returned $loggedIn');
    if (loggedIn == false) {
      try {
        await googleSignIn.signIn();
      } catch (e) {
        print('Login::logIn() - interactive login failed: $e');
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

The `print` statement inside the catch block is never printed, and the app hangs. I've upgraded flutter and re-tested before posting the question - the issue is still there.

(To clarify: The "happy path" -- i.e. user successfully going through the Google sign-in flow -- *works*.)

Comment: I am having the same problem with google sign in 3.0.4

Comment: Any solutions found?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was [fixed](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/commit/7b0c0a39918de036e064aa7eca450407cc5bb84f#diff-69007229df7209b2d3902192b19516e7) in [google_sign_in version 0.2.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in).

Try putting changing your `google_sign_in` dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` to `^0.2.1` and see if that helps.

Comment: I am having the same problem with google sign in 3.0.4. So I do not believe it was fixed